# Print xlxs from ASP on server with no Office product

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, printing, openxml

How can I print an XLSX file from an ASP application?

Situation is: Application running on a server. No Office products can be installed due to license restraints. OpenXML SDK has been used to create and update the spreadsheet. OpenXML SDK apparently has no options for printing within it.

The printer in question is a local printer on the server and the account being used has it set as default

I have attempted 3 different methods to print the file - each with varying levels of success

1.

```
 With myFile
        .UseShellExecute = True
        .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .FileName = fileName
        .Verb = "Print"
    End With
    Process.Start(myFile)
```

This works locally testing - however Office fires up briefly before printing. When testing from the server - nothing happens.

2.

```
 Dim pd As System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog = New System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog

    pd.AllowPrintToFile = True
    pd.AllowCurrentPage = True
    pd.AllowSomePages = True
    pd.AllowSelection = True
    pd.UseEXDialog = True
    pd.PrinterSettings.Duplex = Duplex.Simplex
    pd.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1
    pd.PrinterSettings.ToPage = 1
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.AllPages

    Dim printdoc As New PrintDocument
    printdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1
    printdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.ToPage = 2



    printdoc.DocumentName = filename
    printdoc.Print()
```

This consistently prints blank pages when testing locally and from the server and seems to be the best way forward. It would seem the correct document is not getting through to the printer.

3.
[Code example shown here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

This also works locally and from the server - However the page printed is unintelligible hyroglyphs - What a spreadsheet looks like when you open with Notepad - which is what the xlsx file association is set to on the server.

What's the best option here? One of the above or something else?
Is this even possible? Or am I wasting my time?

The file itself does not need to be xlsx; it just is currently.